# How do I create a link to a saved html page on my computer?

Tags: html

I'm working on a web application that caches html pages and saves it on the user's computer. I want to create a link, so that the user can click on the link and access the cached webpage.

Following is my link to a cached page:

```html
<a href="file:///C:/Users/xxx/yyy/bbc.html">BBC</a>
```

When I click on the link, nothing happens. I'm not even getting any error.
Can someone please suggest how to create a link to a cached html page?

Comment: If the path is correct, it should work.

Comment: Where is the page that contains this link? Does it also get loaded via `file://`? Maybe it's some security feature?

Comment: when I view the page source, and copy and paste the link into the browser address bar, it works. So that path is correct. But if I click on link from a webpage, it does not work.

Comment: What browser are you testing?  I've found IE more receptive to this kind of thing that other browsers.

Comment: Tried IE, FF and chrome.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, not all browsers handle local files equally, indeed, not all computers will be running windows or have a `C:` drive. Secondly, you don't have much control over a user's cache. Cached pages are usually handled by the browser automatically. You can use headers to specify how a browser ought to cache files, but it's not even required to do so. You can read the [W3C recs on caching](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) for more information.

It's unclear what you're trying to do here, but it sounds like it might make more sense for you to use HTML5 local storage or offline files than trying to mess around with their file system directly. The security model of most browsers is such that web apps don't interact with local files, which may be why it's not working for you with your current setup. Dive Into HTML5 has a good overview of HTML5 [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and [offline pages](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html).

---

Edited based on comment below:

Most browsers' security settings won't let a page on a website access files stored locally. Only locally saved files can link to other locally saved files. Therefore, if the page with a link is on a website, your link won't work. Try creating a link to your file from another locally stored file and see if that works.

Comment: I'm only working on a homework problem. Where I have to save a page on a local machine and access it from a link.

Comment: Ah. You may want to add the [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag to your question. As far as solving your problem, it would be helpful to know what browser you're using, and where the page with the link is (online or saved locally?).

Comment: The page with the link is saved on my machine and the link is also to a saved html page on my machine. Tried IE, FF and chrome. Thanks so much in advance for looking into this.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of providing the `.html` extension in the main page where you provide the link you should do something as below:

```
 < href="file:///C:/Users/xxx/yyy/bbc">BBC</a>
```